# Creating a State management with Data Generic in typescript angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Has create Generic StateManagierService which can accept any type, on Change of state the use can get new state and data if any. But look I m missing some thing.

```
export class StateManagierService<T> {
  private _state$: BehaviorSubject<T>;

  protected constructor (initialState: T) {
    console.log("initialState",initialState)
    this._state$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
  }

  get state$ (): Observable<T> {
    return this._state$.asObservable();
  }

  get state (): T {
    return this._state$.getValue();
  }

  changeState (nextState: T): void {
    if(this.state === nextState || nextState === null) return;
    this._state$.next(nextState);
  }
}
```

Different States which user can create

```
export enum state1{
    A =1,
    B
}
```

Wraper Class will create obj and can add more data| properties

```
export class Wrap {
    constructor(stateId: state1, data?:any){
        console.log("stateId", stateId, data)
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class serviceImpl extends StateManagierService<Wrap> {
    constructor(){
        super(new Wrap(state1.A, 'text1')); // Expecting Wrap object to set but not
    }

}
```

Test Service to check

```
class hello {
    constructor(private serviceImpl: serviceImpl){

    }
    one(){
        this.serviceImpl.state$.subscribe(res=>{
          console.log('res', res) // Expecting Wrap object  What im doing wrong
        })
        this.serviceImpl.changeState(new Wrap(state1.B, 'text23'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-order for angular to initialize the properties in the constructor through the shortcut method, we need to define it like `private stateId: state1` doing this solves your issue!

So `<<Access Specifier>> <<propertyName>> : <<Property Type>>` this will be the format!

```
export class Wrap {
  constructor(private stateId: state1, private data?: any) { // <- changed here!
    console.log('stateId', stateId, data);
  }
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lcrj3n?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)